# Get total time and average time in php

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I have got the array of time in following format

```
$array = ('00:01:39','00:03:30','00:05:09','00:10:00','00:00:39','00:02:34','00:06:29','00:26:09','00:13:30','00:07:33');
```

I want the result for total as `01:17:12` and avg as `07:43`

I tried by converting the time to `strtotime`,

and also tried using explode the given time using `:` and processing with it.

but could not get the expected outcome.

I want the simplest way to find the expected result.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
// use example
$array = ['00:01:39','00:03:30','00:05:09','00:10:00','00:00:39','00:02:34','00:06:29','00:26:09','00:13:30','00:07:33'];
echo sum_time($array); # 01:17:12
echo avg_time($array); # 00:07:43

// functions
function calc_time(array $times) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        sscanf($time, '%d:%d:%d', $hour, $min, $sec);
        $i += $hour * 3600 + $min * 60 + $sec;
    }
    return $i;
}
function sum_time(array $times) {
    $i = calc_time($times);
    if ($h = floor($i / 3600)) $i %= 3600;
    if ($m = floor($i / 60)) $i %= 60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $h, $m, $i);
}
function avg_time(array $times) {
    $i = calc_time($times);
    $i = round($i / count($times));
    if ($h = floor($i / 3600)) $i %= 3600;
    if ($m = floor($i / 60)) $i %= 60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $h, $m, $i);
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/142431)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

```
$secs = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);
$total = date("H:i:s",$secs);
$avg = date("H:i:s",$secs/2);
```